# How to add links in my list and retrieve the data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After creating new classroom, the data will then be send to a list as shown on here:
[image]

Now, how do I add/make (a) link/s into every classroom so that whenever I click it it will redirect me to a page and show me their specific data like ClassroomID, students, etc.

here's the code:

```
//retrieving

var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function (data) {

    var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function (key) {
        li.innerHTML += roomNames[key];

    });


});

//adding
function classcreation(q) {
    var checkcn = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
    if (checkcn == "" && checkcn == null) {
        alert("Empty Class Name!!");
    } else {
        var usuid = generateId();
        var myClasses = {};
        myClasses.TheClass = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
        myClasses.Teacher = user.displayName;
        myClasses.TeacherID = user.uid;
        myClasses.ClassID = usuid;
        fbclass.child(user.uid).push().set(myClasses);

    }
}


function generateId() {
    return 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, function () {
        return (Math.random() * 9 | 0).toString();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is adding an Anchor tag within your li which on click would redirect you to a page where class details are shown.
If that is the case edit the following line in your code to (if template string works else use string concatenation to create appropriate string)

```
li.innerHTML += `<a href=${link}>roomNames[key]</a>`
```

If you want to add the classroom details within same HTML without redirecting user try following.

This will append a div to existing HTML where you will show the class info.

```
var infoDiv = document.createElement('div');
infoDiv.id = 'classInfo';
```

On your ul add onclick listener with the following function.

```
ul.onclick = (e) => {
    document.getElementById('classInfo').innerHTML = generateClassInfo(e.target.name); 
}
```

And to your li add name which uniquely identifies a class.

```
li.name= identifier
```

Adding onclick to ul instead of li reduces the number of onclick listeners which is basically a performance optimization.

Take a look at the code sandbox for working example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/q9w9x0vlww

Comment: Thank you so much! Im going to try it. But how about when I click a classroom on my li it will show me the data of it. Not necessarily redirect me to another html

Comment: Let me rephrase it. What I am trying to say is that instead of redirecting me to another html, how about if I click a particular classroom then it will show me the data of it in the same html

Comment: @DodongAdvices edited the answer to accommodate your requirements.

Comment: Im going to try it. Thank you so much! Sorry for the troubles

Comment: I'm confused, where did you get the generateClassInfo and classInfo?

Comment: classInfo is just an id I have used for the div that will display class information. generateClassInfo you have to write which returns whatever info you want to display when li is clicked.

Comment: You know what Mr. Shubham thank you so much for being patient to me. I've been coding for like 6 hrs and my brain is about to explode. Honestly speaking I am not good at this. May I send you my code and help me fix it?

Comment: @DodongAdvices will create a code sandbox and add to the answer give me some time.

Comment: It's just a small web app, nothing fancy. I am having a hard time because I'm noob. If you're going to help me I'm willing to pay for your service.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wfv1cv?file=home.html here's the link ps: it won't run in the stackblitz, maybe in localhost or deploy via firebase deploy

Comment: @DodongAdvices added working example for code sandbox. I can help only this much.

Comment: One last thing Mr. Shubham, can you look at my code on stackblitz at see what did I miss?

Comment: Please reply if you can't. By the way, thank you so much for the help!!!

Comment: just inform me if u can help me fix it or not :( im waiting

Comment: @DodongAdvices won't be able to help any further mate.