# Adding link on list to show its data

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

On my web app, every time a user create a classroom the data will be save to the firebase database and then will be retrieve and sent under the **Classroom:** as shown on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMOcL.jpg).

Now, how do I add or make a link on the list so that when I click a particular classroom it will show me its information like Class name, the Teacher who created it, the students, etc.

Here's my code:

```
function classcreation(q) {
var usuid = generateId();
var myClasses={};
myClasses.TheClass = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
myClasses.Teacher = user.displayName;
myClasses.TeacherID = user.uid;
myClasses.ClassID = usuid;
fbclass.child(user.uid).push().set(myClasses);
 }
}
```

Retrieving the data from the database firebase and then send it to the list

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data) {

var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);

var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
     li.innerHTML += roomNames[key].link(roomNames);

    });


});
```

The  **li.innerHTML += roomNames[key].link(roomNames);** is not yet working, it will just redirect me to another html.

What do I need to add?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>G</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4> Welcome: <span id ="user_name"></span></h4>
<h4>Role: <span id = "user_role"></span></h4>
<br>
<br>
<h3><span id = "jobRole"></span></h3>
<input type="text" id="classroomName"/>
<div id ="teacher_btn">
<button id="create_classBTN">Create</button>
</div>
</br>
<h3><span id = "ListClass"></span></h3>
<div id="myList"></div>

<br> <br>
<button type="button" onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
```

Comment: It appears that `li.innerHTML` is composed to behave to link into another URL. How do you intend to show the `TheClass` object details on your page? You may wish to consider `onClick` instead of a hyperlink for the Room Names and display (`show`) a hidden div which'll have the `TheClass` object properties. Please update your question with the associated HTML markup as well - it'll help bring clarity in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question. How do you add onClick on the javascript?

Comment: You already have a question related to the same issue with answer & Solution as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446430/how-to-add-links-in-my-list-and-retrieve-the-data

Comment: I don't know how to do it using firebase. Can help & teach me how?

Comment: Oh, Ok. It should not be very hard. You may wish to start referring through the official documentation on working with lists: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write Further, if you prefer some video tutorial, please refer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY

Comment: Let me rephrase it, the answer/solution that was given to me is somewhat  similar to the answer I was seeking. But the thing is, the data in the solution is just static,it was just typed in inside the js. Mine is from the firebase database. If I add a new classroom named NeelavarClass it will be stored on the database and then will be retrieve to be sent to the Classroom:, in the NeevalarClass it has a data classroomID, teacher, students. So on the list, I have different classrooms and a room named NeelavarClass . If I click the said class I want to see all the data (classroomID, teacher, etc)

Comment: Please create a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/) and share, so that exact implementation can be updated on your stackblitz code.

Comment: here's the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wfv1cv?file=home.html) I believe it won't run on the stackblitz.com, try running it using localhost or firebase deploy. Thank you so much for the help! Sorry for all the trouble :(

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tcptbk?file=home.js) updated

Comment: Mr. Puff, I really need your help one last time. I swear

Answer (score 0):

Please check response is like anchor tag

> roomNames[key].link(roomNames) should be like `<a href="http://www.goole.com">Anchor</a>`

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.getElementById('mainbar').appendChild(ul);

var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
//Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
    setTimeout(function(){ li.innerHTML += '<a 
     href="http://www.goole.com">Anchor</a>';},5000);

  //  });
```

> Add click Handler

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data) {

var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);

var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
     var classDetails = data.val();
   li.innerHTML += '<span onclick="clickDone(this);">'+roomNames+'</span><ul style="display:none"><li>Class Id : '+classDetails.ClassID+'</li><li>Teacher Id : '+classDetails.TeacherID+'</li><li>Teacher : '+classDetails.Teacher+'</li><li> Class : '+classDetails.TheClass+'</li></ul>';

    });


});
```

> Add this function at last

```
function clickDone(thisVar){ 
     var is = thisVar.nextSibling.style.display;
     if(is == 'none'){
         thisVar.nextSibling.style.display = 'block';
     }else{
         thisVar.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
     }
  }
```

Comment: can I send you my code Mr. Zigri so that you can analyze what mistakes I've made or what code I'm lacking?

Comment: I removed the .link(roomNames) so that it wont redirect me to another page. How do I show the data of a classroom when I click it?

Comment: here's the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tcptbk?file=home.js). The problem was on the home.js part, and I believe it wont run on the stackblitz, try using localhost or firebase deploy. Thank you so much sir! sorry for all the trouble

Comment: just inform me if u can help me fix it :( im waiting

Comment: It says Uncaught ReferenceError: clickDone is not defined

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: clickDone is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (home.html:1)

Comment: All the codes are good, tho I made a few changes in it. But if I click a classroom it says on the console that Uncaught ReferenceError: clickDone is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (home.html:1)... How do I fix it? What's wrong?

Comment: just put the clickDone function out side the block. http://www.aspiration.ai/js-tcptbk

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've a new question. Can you help me again? :(